# Can't detect NDK toolchain path (corrupted NDK installation?)

Tags: android, ruby, android-ndk, rhomobile, rhodes

After developing my first rhomobile app. I am trying to get .apk from Rhomobile suite. Using Ruby 1.9.1, rhodes 5.0.2,ndk R14b, sdk 2.3.1 (64 bit). After putting my project directory in cmd propt and giving rake run:android:device command, i am getting this on console.

```
  TokenValid[YES]
TokenChecked[YES]
SubscriptionValid[YES]
SubscriptionChecked[YES]
RET: 0

PWD: C:\Workspace\RhoWorkspace\PocRho
CMD: rake device:android:production
mkdir -p C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets
mkdir -p C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps
cp -rp lib/framework/autocomplete C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/base64.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/bsearch.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/builtinME.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/date C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/date.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/dateME.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/dateOrig.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/erb.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/find.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/indifferent_access.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/newrhom C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/ostruct.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rational.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rational18.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rationalME.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rbconfig.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/res C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rho C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rho.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhoappmanifest.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhodes-framework.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhodes.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhoframework.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rholang C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhom C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhom.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhomotoapi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhosystem.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/rhosystem_wp8.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/singleton.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/stringio.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/time.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -rp lib/framework/version.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cd C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
rm rhodes-framework.rb
rm erb.rb
rm find.rb
rm builtinME.rb
rm dateME.rb
rm rationalME.rb
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi
cp -r RhoApplicationApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoDatabaseApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoLogApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoNativeMenubarApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoNativeTabbarApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoNativeToolbarApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoNetworkApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoNotificationApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoPushApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoSystemApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r RhoWebViewApi.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json
cp -r json C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cp -r json.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client
cp -r RhoConnectClient.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
rm -rf C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps/public/api
mkdir -p C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps/public/api
Starting rhodes build system using ruby version: 1.9.3
%%%_%%% $js_application = false
%%%_%%% $shared_rt_js_application = false
%%% Prepare capability header file %%%
//#define RHO_NO_RUBY
$app_config['extensions'] : ["coreapi", "json", "rhoconnect-client"]
$app_config['capabilities'] : ["non_motorola_device"]
Using Android SDK build-tools: 25.0.2
$vendor = rhomobile
$app_package_name = com.rhomobile.pocrho
common_bundle_start
C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets
C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
rhoapi_js_folder: C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps/public/api
init extensions
latest_update_time=2014-07-09 00:49:50 +0530
cached_time : 2017-03-28 10:11:27 +0530
ext - coreapi
iter=C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi
extyml C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext.yml
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.ORM.js to startJSModules_opt..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.ORMHelper.js to startJSModules_opt..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.Ruby.RunTime.js to startJSModules_opt..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Application.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Database.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Database.SQLite3.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Intent.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Log.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NativeMenubar.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NativeTabbar.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NativeToolbar.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Navbar.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Network.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NewORM.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NewORMModel.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Notification.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Push.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.RhoFile.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.System.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.System.Process.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.WebView.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add_extension - C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi - C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
chdir path=C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi
ext - json
iter=C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json
extyml C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json/ext.yml
add_extension - C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json - C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
chdir path=C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json
ext - rhoconnect-client
iter=C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client
extyml C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client/ext.yml
add C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client/public/api/generated/Rho.RhoConnectClient.js to extjsmodulefiles..
add_extension - C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client - C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib
chdir path=C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client
exts C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/platform/shared/ruby/ext/rho/extensions.c
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
cp -rp C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/app C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps
cd C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps
cd C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/lib/res
rm back_btn.wm.png
rm blue_pushpin.wm.png
rm blue_pushpin_small.wm.png
rm callout.wm.png
rm callout_link.wm.png
rm esri.wm.png
rm forward_btn.wm.png
rm home_btn.wm.png
rm minimize_btn.wm.png
rm options_btn.wm.png
rm refresh_btn.wm.png
rm sip_btn.wm.png
rm back_btn.win32.png
rm blue_pushpin.win32.png
rm callout.win32.png
rm callout_link.win32.png
rm esri.win32.png
rm forward_btn.win32.png
rm home_btn.win32.png
rm minimize_btn.win32.png
rm options_btn.win32.png
rm refresh_btn.win32.png
rm sip_btn.win32.png
rm back_btn.wp.png
rm blue_pushpin_small.wp.png
rm callout.wp.png
rm callout_link.wp.png
rm esri.wp.png
rm forward_btn.wp.png
rm home_btn.wp.png
rm options_btn.wp.png
rm refresh_btn.wp.png
rm back_btn.wp8.png
rm blue_pushpin_small.wp8.png
rm callout.wp8.png
rm callout_link.wp8.png
rm forward_btn.wp8.png
rm home_btn.wp8.png
rm minimize_btn.wp8.png
rm options_btn.wp8.png
rm refresh_btn.wp8.png
rm sip_btn.wp8.png
cd C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets
cd C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
cp lib/build/compileERB/default.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets
rm C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/default.rb
cp lib/build/compileRB/compileRB.rb C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets
cd C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets
rm apps/app/Application/application.rb
rm apps/app/Application/application_controller.rb
rm apps/app/application.rb
rm apps/app/Candidatedetails/candidatedetails.rb
rm apps/app/Candidatedetails/candidatedetails_controller.rb
rm apps/app/helpers/application_helper.rb
rm apps/app/helpers/browser_helper.rb
rm apps/app/Settings/controller.rb
rm apps/app/Sources/sources.rb
rm apps/app/Sources/sources_controller.rb
rm apps/app/test/application_spec.rb
rm apps/app/test/candidatedetails_spec.rb
rm apps/app/test/model001_spec.rb
rm apps/app/test/products_spec.rb
rm apps/app/test/soles_spec.rb
rm apps/app/test/sole_spec.rb
rm apps/app/test/sources_spec.rb
rm compileRB.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/AddressBar.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Alarm.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Alert.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/AppApplication.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Application.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/AppSwitcher.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/AudioCapture.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/BackButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Backlight.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Barcode.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/BasicSocket.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Battery.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/BottomCommandArea.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/BrowserHelper.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Bsearch.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Camera.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/CardReader.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Comm.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Cradle.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Date.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/DateTime.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/DateTimePicker.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Device.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Digest.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Dir.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Eink.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/EmmlProfile.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/File.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/FileTransfer.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ForwardButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/GeneratorController.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/GeoLocation.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Gesture.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/GoButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/HashWithIndifferentAccess.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/History.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/HomeButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Hourglass.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Imager.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/IoAnalog.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/IoDigital.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/IoSystem.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/IPSocket.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/JSON.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/KeyCapture.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Keylight.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/KeyState.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Lightsensor.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/LocalizationSimplified.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/MapView.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/MediaPlayer.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Memory.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/MinimizeButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/NativeBar.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/NavBar.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Network.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Notification.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/OpenSSL.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Phonebook.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/PowerOn.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Push.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/QuitButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RawSensors.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Reboot.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Registry.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ReloadButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Rfid.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Rho.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhoBluetooth.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhoConf.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Rhodes.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhodesNativeViewManager.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhoElementsExt.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhoLog.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Rhom.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhoProfiler.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RhoStdout.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RHO_APPS_DIR.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RHO_ERB_EXT.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RHO_FRAMEWORK.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/RHO_RB_EXT.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Rsm.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ScanError.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Scanner.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ScreenOrientation.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SignatureCapture.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SignatureTool.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Sip.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SipButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Sntp.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Socket.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SocketError.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SQLite3.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/StopButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/StringIO.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/StringScanner.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Stylus.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SWIG.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SyncEngine.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/System.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/SystemTime.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/TCPServer.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/TCPSocket.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Telemetry.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Thread.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Time.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Timer.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/TopCommandArea.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/UDPSocket.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/VideoCapture.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Volume.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Wake.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/WebView.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Wlan.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/Zoom.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ZoomInPageButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ZoomOutPageButton.rb
rm lib/autocomplete/ZoomTextButton.rb
rm lib/base64.rb
rm lib/bsearch.rb
rm lib/date/format.rb
rm lib/date.rb
rm lib/dateOrig.rb
rm lib/indifferent_access.rb
rm lib/json/common.rb
rm lib/json/pure/generator.rb
rm lib/json/pure.rb
rm lib/json/version.rb
rm lib/json.rb
rm lib/newrhom/newrhom.rb
rm lib/newrhom/newrhom_model.rb
rm lib/newrhom/newrhom_object_factory.rb
rm lib/ostruct.rb
rm lib/rational.rb
rm lib/rational18.rb
rm lib/rbconfig.rb
rm lib/rho/mapview.rb
rm lib/rho/render.rb
rm lib/rho/rho.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoapplication.rb
rm lib/rho/rhobluetooth.rb
rm lib/rho/rhocontact.rb
rm lib/rho/rhocontroller.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoerror.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoevent.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoevent_bb.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoevent_c.rb
rm lib/rho/rhomsg.rb
rm lib/rho/rhonativeviewmanager.rb
rm lib/rho/rhosupport.rb
rm lib/rho/rhotabbar.rb
rm lib/rho/rhotoolbar.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoutils.rb
rm lib/rho/rhoviewhelpers.rb
rm lib/rho.rb
rm lib/RhoApplicationApi.rb
rm lib/rhoappmanifest.rb
rm lib/RhoConnectClient.rb
rm lib/RhoDatabaseApi.rb
rm lib/rhodes.rb
rm lib/rhoframework.rb
rm lib/rholang/lang_en.rb
rm lib/rholang/lang_es.rb
rm lib/rholang/localization_simplified.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhoerror_de.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhoerror_en.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhoerror_es.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhomsg_de.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhomsg_en.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhomsg_es.rb
rm lib/rholang/rhomsg_it.rb
rm lib/RhoLogApi.rb
rm lib/rhom/rhom.rb
rm lib/rhom/rhom_model.rb
rm lib/rhom/rhom_object.rb
rm lib/rhom/rhom_object_factory.rb
rm lib/rhom/rhom_source.rb
rm lib/rhom.rb
rm lib/rhomotoapi.rb
rm lib/RhoNativeMenubarApi.rb
rm lib/RhoNativeTabbarApi.rb
rm lib/RhoNativeToolbarApi.rb
rm lib/RhoNetworkApi.rb
rm lib/RhoNotificationApi.rb
rm lib/RhoPushApi.rb
rm lib/rhosystem.rb
rm lib/RhoSystemApi.rb
rm lib/rhosystem_wp8.rb
rm lib/RhoWebViewApi.rb
rm lib/singleton.rb
rm lib/stringio.rb
rm lib/time.rb
rm lib/version.rb
rm apps/app/Application/edit.erb
rm apps/app/Application/index.erb
rm apps/app/Application/new.erb
rm apps/app/Application/show.erb
rm apps/app/Candidatedetails/edit.erb
rm apps/app/Candidatedetails/index.erb
rm apps/app/Candidatedetails/new.erb
rm apps/app/Candidatedetails/show.erb
rm apps/app/index.erb
rm apps/app/layout.erb
rm apps/app/Settings/err_sync.erb
rm apps/app/Settings/home.erb
rm apps/app/Settings/index.erb
rm apps/app/Settings/login.erb
rm apps/app/Settings/reset.erb
rm apps/app/Settings/wait.erb
rm apps/app/Sources/edit.erb
rm apps/app/Sources/index.erb
rm apps/app/Sources/new.erb
rm apps/app/Sources/show.erb
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2
cp -r platform/shared/db/res/db C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/db
extjsmodulefiles=["C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/jquery-2.0.2-rho-custom.min.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/rhoapi.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Application.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Database.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Database.SQLite3.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Intent.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Log.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NativeMenubar.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NativeTabbar.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NativeToolbar.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Navbar.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Network.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NewORM.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.NewORMModel.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Notification.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.Push.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.RhoFile.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.System.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.System.Process.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/generated/Rho.WebView.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client/public/api/generated/Rho.RhoConnectClient.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.Application.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.Database.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.NewORMHelper.js"]
!!!MODIFY C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps/public/api/rhoapi-modules.js
extjsmodulefiles_opt=["C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.ORM.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.ORMHelper.js", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/public/api/Rho.Ruby.RunTime.js"]
!!!MODIFY C:/Workspace/RhoWorkspace/PocRho/bin/tmp/assets/apps/public/api/rhoapi-modules-ORM.js
end of init extension
Running default.rb

Running compileRB

C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi is configuring...
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext.yml is processing...
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext.yml is processed
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi is configured
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json is configuring...
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/extensions/json is configured
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client is configuring...
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client/ext.yml is processing...
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client/ext.yml is processed
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client is configured
Extensions' java source lists: {"C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi"=>"C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext/platform/android/ext_java.files", "C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client"=>"C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhoconnect-client-5.0.2/lib/../ext/rhoconnect-client/ext/platform/android/ext_java.files"}
{"audio"=>false, "camera"=>false, "gps"=>false, "network_state"=>true, "phone"=>false, "pim"=>false, "record_audio"=>false, "vibrate"=>false, "bluetooth"=>false, "calendar"=>false, "sdcard"=>false, "read_sdcard"=>false, "push"=>false, "motorola"=>false, "motoroladev"=>false, "webkit_browser"=>false, "shared_runtime"=>false, "motorola_browser"=>false, "hardware_acceleration"=>false}
No need to regenerate genconfig.h
rake aborted!
Extension build failed: C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext/platform/android

Tasks: TOP => device:android:production => package:android => build:android:all => build:android:rhobundle => build:android:extensions
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Building coreapi: ["C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext/platform/android", "rake"]
Build extension (arm): coreapi
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PWD: C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite5.0.2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.0.2/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext/platform/android
rake arch:arm
cd ../../..
rake aborted!
Can't detect NDK toolchain path (corrupted NDK installation?)
```

Not sure what is causing it to stop.